# C++ Derived Member Object in Derived Class and how to initialize

Tags: c++, initialization, polymorphism

It seems like a case the you face frequently in C++, but for which I haven't really found a answer.

We have a base class `Car` with a member object `Engine`. Now we derive `Car` to `RaceCar`. That racecar has of course a special engine `SuperEngine`. Now what is the best way to set this up?

The base classes:

```
class Engine{
};

class Car{
public:
    Engine* engine;
    Car(Engine* e): engine(e){}
};
```

The derived classes:

```
class SuperEngine: public Engine{
};

class RaceCar: public Car{
public:
    SuperEngine* engine;
    SuperEngine():
        engine(new SuperEngine),
        Car(engine) // engine is nullptr since this line is called before the above line
        {} 
}
```

In the above example, `Car` is initialized with `nullptr`, because in the initializer list, the base class is called always first, no matter of the order in the initializer list (as far as I can understand). This is of course not what we want.

One workaround is to define a `SuperEngine` object first outside of the classes, and then pass its pointer. But this gets really ugly if you have a lot of members. E.g. Engine, Throttle, Valve etc.. This gives really long constructors, and if you change something, you have to change it 3 times (outside of the class where the `new` is, in the derived class constructor and in the base class constructor).

For me it seems like a natural thing that you have a derived class, which uses derived types of the base class members (like Engine to SuperEngine). Yet it seems not to be covered by tutorials or books (or I am just to dumb to find any).

What would be the best way to implement that (in a way that also makes physical sense)? It should be taken aware of that engine in the base class and engine in the derived class are the same (so the derived class should not shadow the base class engine). So that `Engine` can have a virtual method e.g. `virtual void fullpower();`.

Is there a way to intialize SuperEngine before the base class constructor? Or would you set it up completely different? Looking forward to your ideas!

Comment: Why do you need another `engine` in `RaceCar`? Are you actually going to use specific members that are in `SuperEngine` but not in `Engine`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to use a [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor):

```
class RaceCar: public Car {
public:
    SuperEngine* engine;
    RaceCar() : RaceCar(new SuperEngine) {}
private:
    explicit RaceCar(SuperEngine* se) : Car(se), engine(se) {}
};
```